# Transferring the value in the iphone programming

Tags: iphone

This is my hole code which I am using, I want to transfer scrollViewCintroller Class value in the page2 class.

scrollAppDelegate.h

```
@class scrollViewController;
@interface scrollAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
UIWindow *window;
scrollViewController *viewController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet scrollViewController *viewController;
@end
```

scrollAppDelegate.m

```
#import "scrollAppDelegate.h"
#import "scrollViewController.h"

@implementation scrollAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:     
(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

scrollViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "result.h"
#import "page2.h"
@interface scrollViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UITextField        *txtName; 

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField        *txtName;
- (IBAction)  next           :(id)sender;
```

scrollViewController.m

```
#import "scrollViewController.h"

@implementation scrollViewController
@synthesize txtName;

-(IBAction)next:(id)sender
{
objPage2=[[page2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"page2" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:objPage2.view];       
}
@end
```

I want to use this txtName in other page2 class
page2.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface page2 : UIViewController {

}
@end
```

page.m

```
#import "page2.h"
@implementation page2
```

Comment: When and how do you present page2?

Comment: I am using a button in the scrollViewController, On that button click we go will go to page2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
page1 *obj=[page1 alloc]init];
```

This is making a **new** page1 object. None of the variables you have assigned previously will be available. Your page2 object needs to have a pointer to the actual page1 object you have been using before, it should either be passed in when creating page2 or obtained from the navigation controller or similar, it is not possible to say more without knowIng the structure of your app.

**EDIT**

OK, after your additional code I would suggest the following:

Create a property on your page2 object which refers back to your page 1. Let's call it page1.

In your page2.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) scrollViewController *page1;
```

page2.m:

```
@synthesize page1;
```

When you create your page2 object when the button is pressed, pass the text across at this point:

```
 objPage2.page1 = self;
```

This line goes between your alloc and when you add it to the subview.

You will also need to move `#import "page2.h"` from your scrollViewController.h to your scrollViewController.m, and put `@class scrollViewController;` in your page2.h, and `#import "scrollViewController.h"` in your page2.m

Comment: hi, i have changed my code again(with button option for page2).

Comment: It's working but i want to make object of scrollViewController class inside page2 class and access the variables of scrollViewController.

Comment: In that case, make the property of type scrollViewController, and pass in `self` instead of passing in the string

Comment: I am trying to do this but geting problem, will you provide me some code(plz)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making a class that encapsulates all the values you want to share between the 2 controllers.

Make this class a property of both viewControllers

Then you can create page2 - set the property of page2 from page1 - load page2

Answer (score 0):

Two simple ways -

1. Set those values as properties. Create an object of Class1 in Class2, and access those values.
2. Use `NSUserDefaults`, which is an extremely easy way to share information, and save values in the iPhone app. Check the [Documenation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) , and some tutorials on that!

Edit:

If the property values are NULL, I would suggest store those values in the AppDelegate instance, and then create an instance of the AppDelegate in Class2, and things should be fine !